# Lubuntu boots with black screen in top left corner

Tags: lubuntu

My Lubuntu laptop boots up with a black rectangle taking up most of the screen from the top left corner. However, the bottom and right sides are still visible and I can view the cursor within the black area.

I have a Dell Inspiron 6400 with Lubuntu 14.10.

But here's the strange thing. If I follow this sequence, it eventually boots up OK.

1. Start the grub loader (by holding left shift while booting)
2. Select "Advanced options for Ubuntu"
3. Select "Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-36-generic (recovery mode)
4. Select "resume - Resume normal mode"
5. Click OK
6. I get the full GUI screen. Logging in, I can do everything I need.

So, note that I did **not choose any of the recovery options in safe mode**.

I guess I have a workaround, however this laptop is used by non-techy people, so it would be nice not to have to detail a complicated boot sequence.

Note that I have recently updated the Graphics Card driver so that I could use WebGL. That all works fine after I have booted in this strange manner.

Comment: This question was answered on the Ask Ubuntu forum. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/777458/lubuntu-boots-with-black-screen-in-top-left-corner
The answer is to add the =nomodeset= parameter to the grub loader.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.  You need to edit the grub statement (shift key on boot, then e to edit).  After the word "quiet splash", add the word "nomodeset" and the problem will go away.